# Facebook javascript SDK FB.login is not working in Facebook iFrame

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

We are using Facebook JavaScript SDK to authenticate our Facebook application. The application is configured with the Canvas URL as http://facebook.elgifto.com/Home/Index/. Following is the code we are using to authenticate the Facebook user.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
              debugger;
                  FB.init({
                      appId: '<%= ViewData["AppId"].ToString() %>', // App ID
                      channelUrl: '<%= ViewData["ChannelUrl"].ToString() %>', // Channel File
                      status: true, // check login status          
                      cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                      xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
                      oauth: true
                  });

              FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                  if (response.status === 'connected') {
                      // the user is logged in and connected to your
                      // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                      // the user’s ID, a valid access token, a signed
                      // request, and the time the access token 
                      // and signed request each expire
                      var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                      var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                      startApp(uid, accessToken);
                  }

              });

          };

          // Load the SDK Asynchronously
          (function(d) {    
              var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
              js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
              d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
          } (document));




          function startApp(uid, accessToken) {                 
              var baseUrl = '<%= ViewData["AppBaseURL"].ToString() %>';
              var redirectUrl = baseUrl + '?uid=' + uid + '&accessToken=' + accessToken;
              window.top.location.href = redirectUrl;
              //document.location = redirectUrl;
          }          
       </script>
<fb:login-button onlogin="initiateLogin()" perms="email,user_about_me,user_birthday,friends_about_me,friends_birthday">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

The above code is not working in the Facebook when accessed as http://apps.facebook.com/giftguru. However we are able to access it through http://facebook.elgifto.com/Home/Index

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*?! any errors? or it's not loading the frame at all? have you set the secure link (SSL)?!

Comment: I get the error "The connection has timed out".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is related to pop-up blocking by browser. (the fact that is working for you outside of Facebook is probably because you're allowed to do so sometimes before, for me it's blocked as well as within application).

You should never call `FB.login` without interaction from user (like element `click` or form `submit`) to ensure browser isn't blocking log-in window.

**Update:**
You mixing many things here:

1. Page on `http://facebook.elgifto.com/Home/Index` is using [Application #316853928368079](http://apps.facebook.com/316853928368079/) (this app and have no `namespace`!)
2. Your URL for OAuth Dialog have `'` (apostrophe) around `client_id` which is wrong!
3. OAuth Dialog isn't working (probably also due to app settings, *App Domain*?)
4. Application located on `http://apps.facebook.com/giftguru` is [Application #83808922524](http://graph.facebook.com/83808922524) and have wrong Canvas URL! **Proof**:
   [image: Facebook App Canvas wrapper]

Comment: I tried this solution and it did not work. I changed the code now, please see the changed code. It works when accessed with http://facebook.elgifto.com/Home/Index. But when I access it with http://apps.facebook.com/giftguru, I get "The connection has timed out".

Comment: @mohang, your canvas isn't set to `http://facebook.elgifto.com/Home/Index/` but `http://98.234.246.146:9999/html/home.html` so I'm not able to see it and check

Comment: @mohang, that configuration issue alone may be reason for that *"connection has timed out"* error...

Comment: Can you please explain which configuration issue you are talking about?

Comment: @mohang, I talking about the fact that your **Canvas URL** in [Application Settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/83808922524/summary) isn't pointing to the same page you talking about (`http://facebook.elgifto.com/Home/Index`) but to totally different URL (`http://98.234.246.146:9999/html/home.html`). Ensure that **Canvas URL** is configured properly. BTW, `/html/home.html` isn't event exists in your app on `facebook.elgifto.com`)

Comment: That is not true. The Canvas Url in the facebook app settings is set to http://facebook.elgifto.com/Home/Index/. Still it is not working.

Comment: @mohang, I've updated my answer to provide more details of what I'm talking about...

Comment: I figured this out. Now I am using the OAuth with the namespace selectgifts and my application name is now SelectGifts. The apostrophe around the client_id is removed. Now the connection timed out is gone and the app lets me log in. But it is asking for Secure URL which I am not able to provide.

Comment: @mohang, Secure Canvas URL required to be provided so users who use Secure Browsing on Facebook (`HTTPS`) will be able to use your application. If you in a development phase it's ok not to have a one. But for a final product SSL is requirement and there shouldn't be an issue to get one.

Answer (score 4):

```
  <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'xxxxxxx',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
       
       //LOGIN FUNCTION 
       function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                alert('Success!');
            }else{
                alert('Login Failed!');
            }
        }, {scope: 'email'});
     }
      </script>
      <div onclick="login();">Login with Facebook</div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Also check if your app on deveopers.facebook.com isn't in sandbox mode. I had an issue login worked fine with my main account (which was app admin), but not with other facebook accounts. Later I realized fb app was still in sandbox mode and I had to add each account who was testing as Tester or Developer or disable sandbox mode.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook suddenly switched from using their Facebook dialog method to display the authentication window to old-fashioned popup-windows today. Until now, popup windows have only been used when running apps outside a Facebook tab/canvas. This means that you can no longer run `FB.login` on load and use a click event instead to avoid popup blockers.

The only documentation from Facebook we've found on this is at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/, but apparently, this popup-window method has been available for games for several weeks now.