# Simple Facebook login script not working

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to have the user login to facebook and then display their user id in an alert.

Yet, I get nothing returned by this code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>                                                                                                                                                                      
   <head>                                                                                                                                                                    
     <title>Login to Facebook</title>                                                                                                                                                  
   </head>                                                                                                                                                                   
  <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'APP ID',
            channelUrl : 'http://www.mydomain.net/zoozTest/channel.html',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));

       //LOGIN FUNCTION 
       function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                alert('Success!');
            }else{
                alert('Login Failed!');
            }
        }, {scope: 'email'});
     }
      </script>
      <div onclick="login();">Login with Facebook</div>
    </body>                                                                                                                                                                  
 </html>
```

Comment: Check this link - http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/9938388/842850

Comment: Now I get the popup, but it says An error occurred. Please try again later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook javascript SDK FB.login is not working in Facebook iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820362/facebook-javascript-sdk-fb-login-is-not-working-in-facebook-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

Your code, copied verbatim, works fine for me. Three things:

1: Stupid question, but you've replaced 'APP ID' with your actual app id, right? Otherwise that'll be an error

2: Check your app settings. Have you specified your app domain and 'website with facebook login' URL correctly?

3: Technically you have a race condition. If you click the 'Login with Facebook' div and attempt to run your login() function before the FB JS SDK has initialised (it loads asynchronously), you'll get an error as the global FB object won't be defined. I'd stick a console.log at the bottom of the window.fbasyncinit function to make sure FB is being defined (for testing, for production you'll likely want to either block the login from showing before Facebook is inited, or build some sort of queue that checks to see if the global FB object is defined before attempting to use it, and if not adds to a queue).

Do you have any errors in the javascript console?